# macbook pro 2017 15": screen display a white film that enlighten the vision

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

When I open my laptop the screen becomes so bright that I can not distinguish clearly shades of grey and colors. There is just a hallo all around that is normal but otherwise, all the screen appears with a white film on top like if the image was too luminous.
When I partially close the screen, the problem disappears (see photos)[image]

I tried to reset NVRAM and SMC but nothing changed.

thank you

Comment: This may very well be a hardware problem with the flex cable, so no software reset will help, but someone with more experience in hardware repair will probably be able to confirm my suspicion

Comment: There's an outside chance the display profile has changed. System Prefs > Displays > Colour & try a few different ones. Might be hardware, but this test is at least free.